# Expo / React Native problem displaying events in Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, react-native, google-analytics, expo, firebase-analytics

I build an ecommerce application using expo / firebase / react native, my client asked me to add analytical events in the application from where he would see in firbase all the data provided.

How I started the implementation:
Fallowind documentation provided by [Expo](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/firebase-analytics/) I installed  `expo-firebase-analytics` module,after than I fallow the implementation provided by expo I config my `app.json` adding file that I generated when I created project on firbase `"googleServicesFile":"./google-services.json"`, I learned from their documentation that in order to test these events in the emulator I will have to add siweb config only during development.

```
"web": {
  "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png",
  "config": {
    "firebase": {
    "apiKey": "............",
    "authDomain":"...........",
    "projectId": "..........",
    "storageBucket": "..........",
    "messagingSenderId": ".........",
    "appId": "..............",
    "measurementId": ".................."
    }
  }
}
```

Below I tried to implement the add_to_cart event trying as much as possible to add the data I discovered on this site [Google Analytics 4 Events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events).

```
addItemsToCart = async (product,qty) => {
    //Object that I created to save on redux
    const cartProd = {
        id:product.id_produs,
        product:product,
        qty:qty
    }
    //Call function that save date on redux store...
    this.props.addToCartValue(cartProd);

       //Firebae Await Event that I implemented 
        await Analytics.logEvent('add_to_cart', {
            currency:"RON",
            value:product.pret_mobile*qty,
            items:[
                {
                    item_id:cartProd.id,
                    item_name:product.nume_produs,
                    affiliation: "Google Store",
                    currency: "RON",
                    price: product.pret_mobile,
                    quantity: qty
                } 
            ]
        }).then(() => {
            console.log(' ---------------- Logging add to cart success ------------- ');
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(' ---------------- Logging add to cart failed -------------- ');
        });
    }
```

I don't know now if this is a better implementation but I have a problem when I send the events from the expo go they are registered and `items` are sent.
[image]

but when I compiled the application and adapted it on google play and when I create events in the application it appears like this.

[image]

At build I removed that web config because as they said in the documentation it's just testing, I don't know if I'm wrong in the implementation, I don't send the data correctly considering that `value` and `currency` are sent correctly the problem is to  `items`.

Has anyone tried to implement Firebase Analytics with Expo before they run into the same conva problems, if so how did you manage to get through them.
[image]